# divideSeriesList in Grafana 5.1.0

Tags: grafana, graphite

I have a requirement to divide two series lists. As documentation says "divideSeriesList" function added in Graphite in 1.0.2 version.

So, I updated my Graphite to 1.0.2 and Grafana to 5.1.0. After update, I can see "devideSeriesList" in Graphite but not in Grafana. Where as I can see many other new functions in Grafana after update.

Is there any way I can solve this issue or any alternate way to divide two series lists in Grafana?

Thanks,

Comment: Any solutions now?

Answer (score 1):

List of the functions (https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/public/app/plugins/datasource/graphite/gfunc.ts) in Grafana is static and it's currently out of sync according to graphite. Do not hesitate to make PR to Grafana with updated.

Alternatively you can write your own datasource plugin - http://docs.grafana.org/plugins/developing/datasources/.